# Why does QFT require operator-valued distributions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, dirac-delta-distributions

I am new to QFT, and so far I have only gone through the basics up to defining what a quantum field is, which is an operator valued distribution. I have been struggling so far understanding why operator valued distributions are the right object of study and what motivated this.

For example, the loss of determinism going from classical mechanics to quantum mechanics is (at least from what I understand) the motivation for upgrading observables from scalar-valued maps to operators. What is the analogue for upgrading operators to operator-valued distributions?

Comment: In Halvorson: Algebraic Quantum Field Theory, Section 6, you can find several arguments (which do not rely on imposing canonical commutation relations) why quantum fields cannot be operator-valued functions. For example, Poincaré covariance and the existence of a vacuum vector make quantum fields that are operator-valued functions trivial (Theorem 6.10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about the equal-time commutation relation between the momentum $\pi(x)$ and the coordinate $\phi(x)$: you want to write something like
$$
[\phi(\vec x),\pi(\vec y)]=i\hbar \delta^3(\vec x-\vec y).
$$
For this to make sense, everything should be distributions. That said, this is not exactly the setup of your question because the operator-valued distributions are usually understood in $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$ and not on a time slice.

Another motivation is that thinking about distributions allows you to make sense of the states that you actually create by acting with fields on the vacuum. E.g. to see that
$$
\int d^dx f(x) \phi(x)|0\rangle
$$
is a finite-norm state, you do need to have the test function $f(x)$ and you do need to interpret $\phi(x)$ as a distribution. Without smearing with $f(x)$ you get things like $\langle0|\phi(x)^2|0\rangle=\infty$ and with $f(x)$ you need to make sense of light-cone singularities in the integral, which is where distributions save you.

Finally, people aren't making this stuff up -- there are many QFTs which have been rigorously defined (as in, mathematicians agree they exist), and their fields are operator-valued distributions (by which I mean that they verify Wightman axioms).

A bit more handwaving explanation is that generally the main point of smearing with a test function is to smear in time (in fact, it is enough to smear fields in time only to get operators). What this does is it turns things like $e^{-iEt}$, which are non-decaying at large $E$, into $\int dt f(t) e^{-iEt}$, which decays very quickly at large $E$ if $f$ is smooth. Since you have sums over $E$ everywhere, smearing makes these sums converge.

Comment: One could inject that the distributions are an artefact of an unphysical and rather artificial way of looking at quantum fields. The physical quantities are the S-matrix elements, i.e. the ratios of outgoing to incoming plane wave amplitudes. That doesn't mean the operator formalism is wrong or that point-commutation isn't justified (string theorists might disagree about this point I suppose), it's just not "how nature does it". In nature all quantities of physical relevance are finite all the time.

Comment: @FlatterMann, your comment is very misleading. S-matrix elements are simply not defined for the Standard Model because of IR divergences, and there is a very good physical reason for that. S-matrix is simply not "how nature does it".

Comment: They aren't? CERN is publishing them all the time, both as the result of calculations and as experimental results. I really don't know what you mean. Just because there is a (classical as well as quantum mechanical) low energy divergence doesn't mean that scattering at energies >0 isn't well defined. The divergence can be seen easily in the detectors, too. It's the soft electromagnetic scattering events that are copious and that absolutely nobody cares about (except for the harm they are doing to the machine and maybe as a diagnostics tool). Operators OTOH don't connect to experiments.

Comment: The path integral formulation of QFT is strictly speaking not based on operator valued fields. Moreover, quantum mechanics can also be formulated successfully in terms of the Moyal formalism which does not use operators, but rather distributions of phase space. So operators are not a fundamental requirement for quantum physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann S-matrix elements at energies>0 are not well-defined in (most) gapless theories. LHC measures suitably inclusive cross-sections, not S-matrix elements. Furthermore, LHC has finite size, so it is not even measuring these cross-sections exactly, if you get down into details. As operators, cross-sections in the end are just a theoretical tool. Operators methods are commonplace in HEP, and even more so in other applications of QFT such as to critical phenomena.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Excuse the ignorance of the experimentalist who doesn't know the difference between cross sections and S-matrix elements. I will fix that before my next comment on the matter. I am pretty sure everybody understood what I was trying to say. We never measure anything in physics "exactly", so that's not a problem and we also know from observation that the universe is transparent out to at least 40+ billion light years, so I am sure everybody will agree that it doesn't matter that out to infinity it necessarily has to be opaque... because... obviously not even the universe cares.